# the web server cannot connect to specified data source

Tags: sharepoint-designer, external-content-type

[image]
I have been trying to connect to a OLEDB data source using SharePoint designer custom connection string and receiving an error.

Provider=myProvider;Data Source=myPath;Initial Catalog=catalogName;

User Id=username;Password=password;

Any help would be appreciated.